# The app references non-public selectors in Payload/<Appname>.app/<App name>: decoder

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api, ios7, socket.io, xcode5

I am getting this warning while submitting app to the Apps store through organizer.

> The app references non-public selectors in Payload/.app/: decoder

i know we get this warning if we use any Third Party API in our application. I have used [SOCKETIO-ObjC](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc) library for chat functionality in application. Also used facebook iOS sdk for fb implementation.So i am not getting exactly what causes this warning.! Please find attached [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FayAJ.png) for better understanding

Comment: In my case getting error regarding "AWSAuthCore: reloadSession". I received a mail regarding uploading error from apple. They mentioned that AWS will use camera. For that i have to add Camera Permission in info.plist.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You may get this warning just for using a selector in your own code or third party code that has the same name as some selector that is marked as non-public. Happens to me all the time. Never got rejected for it.

By "same name" i mean just something as simple as you having an object with this selector:

```
-(id) XYZKMyClass doSomethingFancy:(id) toThis
```

...and there being a selector like this for an internal Apple functionality

```
-(id) ApplesClass  doSomethingFancy:(id) toSomething
```

So: What it seems they are looking for is the signature -(id) doSomethingFancy:(id). You can see how it's very easy to accidentally bump up against this.

Presumably they perform a deeper check at the App Store Police HQ, and determine that the flagged selector is in your code, and hence OK.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry I can't get you a link to an official explanation, but I haven't been able to find any on this topic. All I can say for sure is that this happens to me every time I submit an update to my primary app, and nothing bad has happened so far.

Comment: I wish there was a way to search for the non-public selector so that I could rename it.

Comment: Aware that this thread is months old but ... Is there way to be informed of the namespace collision at compile/build time rather than after submitting the app to the store?

Comment: Hi Byron, sorry if there is I have not found it.

Comment: can apple will reject for same warning like :

    The app references non-public selectors in Payload/.app/: id

@AndersJohansen

Comment: What do you mean Dhaval?

Comment: @DhavalBhadania I have not been rejected and have submitted updates multiple times.

Comment: I was just so lazy I didn't see that it didn't stop the app to upload to iTunes Connect. Thanks, mate.

Comment: Any idea for searching such public selector ?

Answer (score 4):

This can help you:

**Before:**

```
#import "SocketIOJSONSerialization.h"

extern NSString * const SocketIOException;

// covers the methods in SBJson and JSONKit
@interface NSObject (SocketIOJSONSerialization)

// used by both JSONKit and SBJson
- (id) objectWithData:(NSData *)data;

// Use by JSONKit serialization
- (NSString *) JSONString;
**- (id) decoder;**

// Used by SBJsonWriter
- (NSString *) stringWithObject:(id)object;

@end
```

**After:**

```
#import "SocketIOJSONSerialization.h"

extern NSString * const SocketIOException;

// covers the methods in SBJson and JSONKit
@interface NSObject (SocketIOJSONSerialization)

// used by both JSONKit and SBJson
- (id) objectWithData:(NSData *)data;

// Use by JSONKit serialization
- (NSString *) JSONString;
**- (id) jsonDecoder;**

// Used by SBJsonWriter
- (NSString *) stringWithObject:(id)object;

@end
```

I get in this link: http://blog.csdn.net/erica_sadun/article/details/12188083

Answer (score 1):

Check your **Target Membership** for all classes used in project. In some cases when you create or copy your target the warning may appears without link error.