# iTunes : App Upload Warning : The app references non-public selectors in :renderedImage

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0, box2d

While uploading the binary app to iTunes, it reports warning as follows:

```
The app references non-public selectors in :renderedImage
```

How can I solve this issue?
Which public API can resolve the issue (`:renderedImage`) ?

Comment: may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378484/the-app-references-non-public-selectors-in-payload-appname-app-app-name-dec