# non public selector heightForRow:AtIndex in cocos2d during validation in Xcode 6

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ios8, xcode6

Recently I have updated my Xcode to 6.0.1 from v 5.1.1. While during validation of my current Cocos2d v3.1 project the iTunes store was showing me the warning

```
iTunes Store operation failed.
The app references non-public selectors in Payload/<AppName>.app/<AppName>:tableView:heightForRowAtIndex:
```

[image: Validation Warning]

Is there any way out to resolve this validation warning?

Comment: FWIW issue raised at https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-swift/issues/1012

Answer (score 3):

Oh,it was due to the CCTableView class in Cocos2d 3.1 library. There is a method name `- (float) tableView:(CCTableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndex:(NSUInteger) index;` in `CCTableViewDataSource` declared in `CCTableView.h`. Probably this method is also declared in some other class and `CCTableView.m` was calling this method by invoking `[dataSource respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:heightForRowAtIndex:)];`.

I have changed the method name by declaring it as - `(float) ccTableView:(CCTableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndex:(NSUInteger) index;` in `CCTableViewDataSource` and changed the corresponding invocation in `CCTableView.m` file by replacing `[dataSource respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:heightForRowAtIndex:)];` by `[dataSource respondsToSelector:@selector(ccTableView:heightForRowAtIndex:)];` and `[_dataSource tableView:self heightForRowAtIndex:i];` by `[_dataSource ccTableView:self heightForRowAtIndex:i];`.

Comment: Cool I will do this too. Let's hope the Cocos2D team fixes it too... although it looks like some script at ITC is at fault really...

Comment: Just renaming the discussed method solved my issue, iTunes connect validated my app successfully. What is the present status of your app? Is it facing the same validity warning from iTunes Connect?

Comment: Yes, it's a warning/issue that stems from lack of namespaces. I renamed the staff and no name collision happen. Here is another question/answer explaining this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378484/the-app-references-non-public-selectors-in-payload-appname-app-app-name-dec

Comment: Will apple reject app if I just leave this warning as is?

Comment: @LocPham I have previously submitted ipa with validation warning, and Apple has not rejected it. But it's always suggested to resolve each and every validation warning.

Comment: My app got rejected because of this

Comment: Make sure if you use XCode's refactor > replace functionality that you go through and double-check for the @selector calls, for example:
`dataSource respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:heightForRowAtIndex:)`