# the app references non-public selectors in payload/

Tags: ios, ios7, non-public-selectors

I'm facing an issue at time of binary submission to app store from Application Loader. I'm submitting this app for second version. I received this error :the app references non-public selectors in payload/ appname .app/ appname id:_terminateWithStatus:,tableView:heightForRowAtIndex

i can't use tableView in my app.

please help me to solve this bug

Comment: You're referencing a private selector in your app. most likely in a tableView:heightForRowAtIndex ? SHouldn't this be: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: Are you using cocos2d?

Comment: Did you check the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378484/the-app-references-non-public-selectors-in-payload-appname-app-app-name-dec ?

Comment: In my case getting error regarding "AWSAuthCore: reloadSession". I received a mail regarding uploading error from apple. The mentioned that AWS will use camera. For that i have to add Camera Permission in info.plist.