# the app reference non-public selectors in payload/appname.app/app: attribution

Tags: ios, submit, app-store-connect

I tried to submit an app to the iOS Store and I got that warning

the app reference non-public selectors in payload/appname.app/app: attribution

I tried to submitted with that warning but it's stuck in the build, and I can't select it to submit it to the review.

Please does anyone have a solution or an idea how can I fix that, Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The app references non-public selectors in Payload/<Appname>.app/<App name>: decoder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378484/the-app-references-non-public-selectors-in-payload-appname-app-app-name-dec)

Comment: it's not the same, that one has "decoder" my problem is "Attribution"

Comment: Im having this exact problem too. I am not using any method called "attribution" but apple warns me about it. I do use Google Admob SDK though not sure if Google has that functino in their SDK?